# Search Tools not expanding for Advanced Module Manager

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, php7, module-manager

My joomla 3.6.4 site has been recently upgraded to Php7.1.33
I am seeing one issue in Advanced Module Manager. "Search Tools" are not expanding for it. It is expanding for Article Editors and in other locations.

[image]

In broswer console logs, found these errors.

[image: Error displaying on browser]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour]. Please continue to investigate this issue while you wait for feedback/support.  If you discover any new clues please edit your question.  If you manage to resolve your own issue, please post an answer to your own question.

Comment: PHP7.1 became an unsupported branch on 1 Dec 2019.  https://www.php.net/eol.php  PHP7.2 will only be a supported branch until 30 Nov 2020.  https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php  If broken applications aren't enough to motivate upgrading, what else will do it? I have spoken at [our monthly JUG Meetup](https://www.meetup.com/Joomla-Users-Group-Brisbane/) about an initiative where people can attempt to upgrade while being supported by a team of volunteers that are experienced at upgrading.  My feeling is that the task is intimidating for those that lack experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joomla.getOptions` is a JS function available in Joomla 3.7+, hence the reason you have this error. You have two options:

- Source an *older* version of Advanced Module Manager which is
  compatible with Joomla 3.6.X. This option is not advised due to [multiple security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/3496/Joomla.html) in your version of Joomla.
- Upgrade to the latest Joomla 3.9.X, which will solve this particular
  issue, as well as the vast majority of [known vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/3496/Joomla.html).

Comment: Thanks .It worked after upgrading Joomla to 3.7.0 and Advanced Module Manager to compatible version.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to **keep your software up-to-date**.Your **Joomla 3.6.4** has been released in October 2016.

The most recent Joomla version is **Joomla 3.9.19** (June 2020). In between those versions, whole bunch of issues (including some security issues) have been fixed. It's a waste of time to try fixing issues with outdated software. Those issues might have been fixed already in the current version.

Please **update your extensions + Joomla** to the most recent versions, and then test again. Make sure that you **create a backup** (files + database) before doing those updates, for example using Akeeba Backup.

Comment: You are right. Spent unnecessary time applying hacks to make it work. Upgrading to joomla 3.7.0 worked well.

Comment: Good to hear that you've solved it. Why did you choose to update to 3.7.0 and not the latest version 3.9.19? There have been a number of releases since 3.7 to fix some minor security issues. And with every minor release version (3.7.0, 3.8.0, 3.9.0) new features have been added to improve Joomla's core functionality.

Comment: I was hesitant to do a big jump as there are some timelines. So far all known issues are fixed and may be I will get some breathing period to review and upgrade joomla and php further